# Prevent children from underflowing if parents' width is smaller (no float or absolute positioning)

Tags: html, css

I have two divs with fixed width placed next to each other in a parent div. I want to prevent the two divs to be placed under another if the parents' width becomes smaller than the childrens combinded width. They should stay next to each other, and overflow the parent.

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qk0qrj54/1/)

As you can see I want the two children to overlap with relative positioning. This leaves a lot of blank space in the parent that I want to eliminate.

Because I want the height of the parent to adapt to the tallest child (assume that the height changes and is not fix) I can not use `float` or `position: absolute;` which makes it tricky.

I am out of ideas. Any suggestions?

I would like the solution to include at least IE8.

Comment: – Very unclear what you're asking here.  An illustration as to what you're after or perhaps some examples elsewhere would be helpful. As described, I'm having difficulty understanding the exact behavior you're after.  Also, in the future please include some example code when linking a JSFiddle.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, just add the property "white-space: nowrap;" to the parent element.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qk0qrj54/2/

```
#parent {
 background-color: yellow;
 width: 380px; 
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Aaah thank you! That property only comes to my mind when it comes to text. I never thought of using it like that!